# How to move 1tb table from RDS MySql database to bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-rds

I have a tables with composite key of three columns, size of table is 330 GB but size of index is 660 GB.

Currently I am working on solution to select the data and export it as csv to gcs, after which it will be loaded in BigQuery.

Selecting on the basis of limit and offset, is taking a lot of time. Is it better to partition table on something like creation time column and then migrate it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google BigQuery is able to import from Parquet and you can export an RDS snapshot to parquet.

- [The docs tell you how to export a snapshot to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html).
- Afterwards you could move these files to GCP and [import them to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet).

Exporting the snapshot to S3 doesn't actually impact your database as it runs in the background. Since parquet is heavily compressed this is probably good for your data transfer costs as well ;-)

Comment: Hi maurice, Thanks for the reply. I was following your approach, but in this approach AWS asks to encrypt the snapshot with KMS, will this encryption affect the data import on bigquery.

Comment: That just means your source database is KMS encrypted - I don't think it's a big deal. Once you download the files from S3 they won't be encrypted anymore - otherwise S3 won't even let you download them. You probably have decrypt-access to the key anyway, so it will probably be fine.